# How to return value from general comparisons in XQuery?

Tags: xquery

I currently have this query, but it only returns a boolean value TRUE.

```
let $expression1 := (0, 11, 22, 34, 36, 57)
let $expression2 := (16, 17, 57, 18)

for $item in ($sequence1 = $sequence2)
return $item
```

This query currently returns the boolean TRUE.
How would I be able to return a sequence of two values: the value of the first expression and the value of the second expression instead?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: The variables $sequence1 and $sequence2 are not defined. It sounds like you are expecting a nested sequence ((0,11,22,34,36,57), (16,17,57,18)). XQuery flattens nested sequences to ordinary sequences, so there is no concept of nested sequences. You need to use XML for nested data structures in XQuery. I can give an answer if this is what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a boolean result because `($sequence1 = $sequence2)` evaluates to "Is there any value in `$sequence1` equal to any value in `$sequence2`?". This evaluates to `for $item in true() return $item`, which returns the single boolean.

If you want to return only values that are in both sequences:

```
return $sequence1[. = $sequence2]
```

If you want to return both sequences together:

```
return ($sequence1, $sequence2)
```

If you want to return both sequences without duplicates:

```
return distinct-values(($sequence1, $sequence2))
```